# wifi hardware switch doesn't work on a Dell 1018

Tags: wireless, dell, inspiron

I have a problem with my Dell 1018 Inspiron. I can't switch the wifi on, through the key on the keyboard. I think it's a driver problem since Ubuntu 11.10. This are the versions i tried:

Ubuntu 10.04 / 10.10 It's possible to install the driver by hand:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lexical/hwe-wireless
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192ce-dkms
```

Ubuntu 11.04 It works out of the box

Ubuntu 11.10 / 12.04 I haven’t found any solution for these versions. The "`ppa:lexical/hwe-wireless`" doesn't work for these versions. It says Can not find package rtl8192ce-dkms.
The window of additional drivers is empty. So I can't install the driver.

The wired network works good.

Here  is some information:

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

---

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 5c:26:0a:0d:20:10
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0f2c000-f0f2cfff memory:f0f18000-f0f1bfff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 70:f1:a1:fe:15:bd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.2.0-22-generic-pae firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.76 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0100000-f0103fff
mark@mark-Inspiron-1018:~$
```

---

```
mark@mark-Inspiron-1018:~$ sudo lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation N10 Family DMI Bridge [8086:a010]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:a011]
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:a012]
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 [8086:27d0] (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 [8086:27d2] (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:27c8] (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:27c9] (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:27ca] (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:27cb] (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller [8086:27cc] (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller [8086:27bc] (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:27c1] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller [8086:27da] (rev 02)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
mark@mark-Inspiron-1018:~$
```

---

```
mark@mark-Inspiron-1018:~$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 174f:1127 Syntek 
mark@mark-Inspiron-1018:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

ditto! same machine same problem....sleuthed around this site...installed synaptic package manager from the ubuntu software center...using that installed firmware-b43-installer and made sure jockey-gtk was installed

then the magic trick....boot into bios (F2)....restore the bios to default settings...and hey presto..everythings working like a charm  including the Wicd Wireless Network Manager.

I'm a beginner and it sounded complicated but it wasnt really..!

Comment: Really thank you for your quick answer! I've heard of that solution with the 'reset' of the Bios. And yes this can solve it. But why does it work with Ubuntu 11.04 so well, and not with the later versions?